# Batching for tf.learn input_fn in tensorflow 1.0

Tags: tensorflow

When using an input function to feed training data to tf.learn what is the best method in tf 1.0?

I was using learn.dataframe.queues.feeding_functions.enqueue_data in tf0.12 but having explored tf.train.batch, tf.train.slice_input_producer and tf.FIFOQueue I am not sure how to rewrite this for tf1.0.

The code I was using is

```
    def pandas_input_fn(x, y=None, batch_size=128, num_epochs=None):
 def input_fn():
    if y is not None:
        x.loc[:,'y'] = y
    queue = learn.dataframe.queues.feeding_functions.enqueue_data(
      x, 1000, shuffle=num_epochs is None, num_epochs=num_epochs)
    if num_epochs is None:
        features = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size)
    else:
        features = queue.dequeue_up_to(batch_size)
    features = dict(zip(['index'] + list(x.columns), features))
    if y is not None:
        target = features.pop('y')
        return features, target
    return features
return input_fn
```

from https://medium.com/@ilblackdragon/tensorflow-tutorial-part-4-958c29c717a0#.4vwo2ato7